# angularjs how to get drop target index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to using the angularjs drag and drop according to this [**link**](http://ganarajpr.github.io/angular-dragdrop/). (GitHub Link)

However, in this link, one draggable element can only be drop to the end of the array.

I am thinking that if I can get the drop target index, then could exchange two element places.

But I am not sure how to get the drop target index. Could someone look into this and help me on that?

Thanks in advance!